# .htaccess to allow me to view php and html files in a subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to install moodle into a subdirectory of a website. However there is a home-brew CMS on there already and the .htaccess is causing me problems. How would I change the file below to get normal website results in the subdirectory /moodle/ so it displays a page such as /moodle/test.php or /moodle/test.html in an expected manner?

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag log_errors on

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}                ^([^:]+)
RewriteRule ^assets/documents/([0-9]+)/?.*$    /home/user/htdocs/scripts/document.scr.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^logout/.*$    /home/user/htdocs/scripts/logout.scr.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^assets/.*$ -   [L]
RewriteRule ^cms/.*$        -   [L]
RewriteRule ^uploads/.*$    -   [L]
RewriteRule ^scripts/.*$    -   [L]
RewriteRule ^phpMyAdmin/.*$ -   [L]

RewriteRule ^.*$        index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude `moodle/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^moodle/
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

Everything else will be handled by the CMS' entry point `index.php`

Comment: Strangely that doesn't work. I can load the file /assets/test.html but not /moodle/test.html. What else could be going on?

Comment: I had the wrong code, add a rewrite condition to the catch-all to ignore `moodle/`

Comment: That should be the gist of it. Tinker with it.

Comment: it worked :) it turned out that i was editing "htaccess" while the *real* ".htaccess" file was hidden from me